# How to load records from mongodb with limit using spring data

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I want to load only 100000 records which are in NOT_STARTED status in mongodb and want to process those records and update status to STARTED. I want to repeat this process until all the records which are in NOT_STARTED status processed.

Currently i am using Pagerequest as shown in the below code and it seems working. But is there a way i can do this without pagerequest having my repository extends spring MongoRepository. Because Pagerequest seems for pagination. But i am not doing any pagination only loading 100000 records each time and processing them

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "_id");
int count = (int) PaymentReportRepository.count();
for(int i = 0; i < count; i += reportProperties.getPageSize()) {
List<PaymentReport> paymentReportList =
        MongoTraceability.capture(() ->
        PaymentReportRepository.findByStatusAndDateLessThan("NOT_STARTED",
                LocalDateTime.now().minusSeconds(reportProperties.getTimeInterval()),
                ,PageRequest.of(0, reportProperties.getPageSize(), sort)));

        if (paymentReportList != null && !paymentReportList.isEmpty()) {
            for (PaymentReport paymentReport : paymentReportList) {
                   messageService.processMessage(paymentReport);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're processing each record synchronously.  Do you have any desire/ability to process asynchronously?

Will this solution be run off a single JVM?

From your question I'm assuming synchronous processing and a single JVM.

I would use [Spring's MongoTemplate class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#reference).  Example tutorials/examples here: https://www.baeldung.com/queries-in-spring-data-mongodb

MongoTemplate will allow you to write your query along the lines of `query("NOT_STARTED").limit(100000)` to return the results you want.  Assuming your `messageService.processMessage(paymentReport);` is doing an `update()` to the document after it is done processing and updates its status, then your next query will retrieve the next 100000 messages with your desired status.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rename `findByStatusAndDateLessThan` to `findFirst100000ByStatusAndDateLessThan`